# example of when the likelihood function does not sum up, or integrate to $1$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, density-function, likelihood

Could someone please give an example of when the likelihood function does not sum up, or integrate to $1$? I have seen [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31238/what-is-the-reason-that-a-likelihood-function-is-not-a-pdf) question with the first answer but it really confused me - why are we integrating the likelihood function and not summing it up with the $\sum$ sign? Since it is a Bernoulli distribution (discrete). If someone could clarify my confusion and maybe provide more example(s), that would help I think.

Comment: probability is always scaled to 1. likelihood doesn't need to be scaled. so you can create an infinite number of examples by taking a probability and dropping the scale

Comment: yes, I shouldnt have included the "pdf integrating to 1" part as it always does. But an example of the likelihood not scaling to 1 would be nice

Comment: Almost any likelihood you choose won't "scale to 1", as the variable(s) is/are the parameters, not the random variable of the probability function (which is scaled to integrate to 1.)  There is literally no reason why a likelihood *would* integrate to 1 except by chance.

Comment: well then could you give an example? Also, i dont understand in the question referenced, why do we integrate it, not sum it up?

Comment: I am uncertain if I should mention something like Jeffreys prior or Haldane's prior just as an example of "obviously funny" likelihoods...

Comment: "Integrate to one" implies using a specific measure on the parameter space. Likelihood functions are not naturally endowed with such a measure. The question is thus groundless.

Comment: To add to the fundamental remark voiced by @Xi'an, note that the likelihood is only defined up to a multiplicative constant in the first place and, depending on the density one *arbitrarily* chooses for integrating it, it might be (and often is) impossible to normalize it to integrate to unity as the axioms of probability demand.

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284816/why-do-people-use-mathcall-thetax-for-likelihood-instead-of-px-theta/284827#284827)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood in the linked question is $$L(\theta)=P(X=x|\theta)=\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}$$
Here $X$ is a Bernoulli RV, and the likelihood function is actually a probability mass function in terms of $x$. So, you can sum wrt $x$ and obtain $1$. However, likelihoods are typically for observing/estimating the parameter when the data is given, i.e. $x$'s. So, the variable in likelihood function is the *parameter*, i.e. $\theta$. And, since it is continuous, the answer integrates it with respect to $\theta$ and shows that it doesn't have to be $1$.

Comment: "and since it's continuous" ? The likelihood is continuous? But where is it said that it's continuous? Maybe i'm missing something from the defintion

Comment: The $\theta$ is a continuous variable which can be any real value between $0$ and $1$ if not stated otherwise.

Comment: ohhh okay, okay. I see now! Thanks so much for clarifying this!

Comment: A more fundamental issue: Why integrating wrt the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$ and not 12.46 times the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$? or $\exp(-5\pi)$ times the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$?